# vbs smtp sending emails

Tags: email, vbscript, smtp

I am trying to write a script that sends me some informations from a given text file. I tried multiple ways of error handling but I can't get past the following error:

> Error setting From address : The requested body part was not found in
> this message

I will leave all emails empty in this post but in my code I made sure to have all required inputs given.

```
Function SendEmail()
    ' Email details
    Dim objMessage, strTo, strFrom, strSubject, strBody
    Dim strSMTPServer, intSMTPPort, strSMTPUsername, strSMTPPassword

    strTo = ""
    strFrom = "" 
    Do
        strSubject = InputBox("Enter a Title", "Ticket Subject")
    Loop Until strSubject <> ""
    
    strBody = InputBox("Enter a message", "Ticket Body")
    
    ' Read the content of the text file
    strTextFile = strCurrentPath & "\info.txt"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile, 1)
    strFileContent = objTextStream.ReadAll
    objTextStream.Close

    If strBody <> "" Then 
        strBody = strBody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strFileContent
    Else 
        strBody = strFileContent
    End If

    MsgBox strBody
    
    ' SMTP server configuration
    strSMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
    intSMTPPort = 587
    strSMTPUsername = "" ' Use your Office 365 email address
    strSMTPPassword = "" ' Use your Office 365 email password

    On Error Resume Next ' Start error handling
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Error creating CDO.Message object: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Stop error handling

    ' Set the email properties
    On Error Resume Next ' Start error handling
    With objMessage
        .From = strFrom
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "Error setting From address: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
        End If
        .To = strTo
        .Subject = strSubject
        .TextBody = strBody

        ' Configure the SMTP server
        With .Configuration.Fields
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPServer
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = intSMTPPort
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = strSMTPUsername
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = strSMTPPassword
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
            .Update
        End With
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Stop error handling

    ' Send the email
    On Error Resume Next ' Start error handling
    objMessage.Send
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Error sending email: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Email sent successfully using Office 365 SMTP."
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Stop error handling
End Function
```

Comment: `strFrom` is never set in this code.

Comment: I think by leaving all emails blank, you are obsuring the problem. Post the script with dummy emails (making sure you actually get the same error with those dummy emails)

Comment: I get the same error code for all the email properties. I have used multiple emails now (yes they were for office 365 ). I have read soemthing about system language by other users but that didnt do the trick as well

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville as mentioned I made sure to not post there here but I did not leave them blank when trying to run the code

Comment: I was under the impression that user and password authentication is [not supported via SMTP on Office 365 anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365).